# Vue.js including non-npm JavaScript library

Tags: vue.js

I'm a total beginner with Vue.js and struggling to find the answer to what I feel is a fairly basic need.
I have a JavaScript library that cannot be installed locally and must be imported via script tag in the index.html file in the old-fashioned way:

```html
<script src="https://foo.bar/scriptyscripts.js"></script>
```

This library has a bunch of methods in it that I need to use in various spots throughout my app, so it's not going to be a problem to load it globally. The issue I'm facing is that it's loading fine, but the methods are not being recognised in components.

I can use the methods and whatnot if I put them all in a script tag in the index.html however doing that rather defeats the whole point of having components.

Can anyone help me with the step that I'm missing to register all of the methods in this loaded js file so my components don't get mad?

Specifically, the script contains require.js and a collection of other things including JQuery.
Including the library makes the method 'require' available, which is used to load other modules on demand - the example being "js/qlik" in the below snippet. "js/qlik" loads JQuery and a stack of stuff associated with "qlik".

```js
  
//async login method here. not relevant to this problem

    login().then(() => {
      require.config({
        baseUrl:
          (config.isSecure ? "https://" : "http://") +
          config.host +
          (config.port ? ":" + config.port : "") +
          config.prefix +
          "resources",
        webIntegrationId: config.webIntegrationId,
      });
      //Load js/qlik after authentication is successful
      require(["js/qlik"], function (qlik) {
        qlik.on("error", function (error) {
          $("#popupText").append(error.message + "<br>");
          $("#popup").fadeIn(1000);
        });
        $("#closePopup").click(function () {
          $("#popup").hide();
        });
 
        var app = qlik.openApp("caa866be-c8e1-44c8-b67b-dac9d24421fa", config);


      });
    });
```

The problem I have is that if I load this library in the index.html file and then try to execute the methods in the snippet above in any component, it does not know that the methods are available.

I see:

'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'js/qlik'

66:11  error  '$' is not defined

which indicates that the components are unaware of the methods because they're not registered like they would be if I were importing a packaged afterinstalling it locally via NPM

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown what went wrong. The question doesn't make sense in general for a random lib and is specific to your case

Comment: Ok, thanks. More details added

Answer (score 0):

i.e. Your original js code: `function abc(){// sth...}`
What you need: `window.abc = ()=>{// sth...}`
Even if you want it in Vue dom.
You should add `vue.prototype.abc = ()=>{//sth...}`